# Java lwjgl glVertex2f sizes

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to use lwjgl do draw a 64x64 pixels square on a window with the following code:

```
 glColor3f(1f,1f,1f);
 glBegin(GL_QUADS);
 glVertex2f(0, 0);
 glVertex2f(0, 64);
 glVertex2f(64, 64);
 glVertex2f(64, 0);
 glEnd();
```

I noticed that the size of the square isn't 64x64 pixels, but it's 100x100 pixels. I used the following code to track the mouse

```
int pX = Mouse.getX();
int pY = Mouse.getY();
System.out.println(pX + " " + pY);
```

I tried dividing the pointer's coordinates by 1.6 and 1.53 and now they're right for some reason:

```
int pX = (int)(Mouse.getX()/1.6);
int pY = (int)(Mouse.getY()/1.53);
```

What unit of measure does glVertex2f use and why does it use a different one from Mouse.getX and Mouse.getY? How can I fix the issue? Thanks

Comment: I use glfw, but it has similar pitfalls, where the mouse callback is using OS screen coordinate units, not necessarily pixels, so you shouldn't make the assumption.

Comment: Oh ok thanks. How can I let it use the same unit of measure?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the usage of glVertex2f or lwjgl, but my guess would be you need to use normalized coordinates instead of pixels/screen coordinates, where {0.5, 0.5} would correspond to middle of screen for both GL and your mouse api. Hopefully the docs can point you in the right direction to go about this.